# JWT validation using Jwts.parser giving Invalid signature

Tags: java, jwt

I have a token issued by Azure AD. I need to verify the token in my API, which is running on IBM platform.
I am writing the token verifier in Java,using
claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKeyResolver(signingKeyResolver).parseClaimsJws(accessToken);
The signingKeyResolver is returning a public key. No issues.
I use the following code to get the public key :

```
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(key.getN()));
                BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode(key.getE()));

                RSAPublicKeySpec publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
                KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                Provider provider = factory.getProvider();
                PublicKey pubkey = factory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
                return factory.generatePublic(publicSpec);
```

Can any one throw some light on Why the signature is invalid ? I observe one thing when I create the factory, the Provider name shows IBMJCEPLUS. Does it have any impact on the key generation ? If so, how do I create the correct factory for Microsoft issued keys ?

Looking for a general advice in creating the factory..

Comment: I am using the sample code on GitHub  https://github.com/sangonzal/jwt-validation-java Only thing I am running on IBM integration platform as a module instead of a standalone Java program. Also, the description of this code is well documented here.. https://sgonzal.com/2020/04/06/jwt-validation.html.

Answer (score -1):

Several things.

1. the sample is incomplete, and seems mixed up. Is this the role of consumer doing a signature verification?
2. You are generating a public key which is not an expected behaviour for the verify method of a consumer, you typically 'use' the JWK retrieved from the JWKS URL provided by the JWT producer (AzureAD) not generate a new public key that was not used to generate the signature? To verify a signature, you need to reproduce the same signature by having all the inputs the server used when they generated it. A signature is simply a representation of the payload to ensure the payload was not modified, i.e. integrity check. This is the purpose of the signature and why you must have the same inputs to generate it on the client, wither you gain the inputs used out-of-band somehow (not how AzureAD works) or you use the JWKS to retrieve the appropriate public key for the verify method.
3. It appears you also expect there to be encrypted claims, based on the RSA reference in your example. If this is intended you would also require you to *decipher* the payload to access the *cleartext*. This requires you to have implemented the appropriate PKI. As a consumer (client) the private key must be generated and never shared (or retrieved). Encryption implemented correctly ensures that only the client intended to read the cleartext data 'can' decipher it with the private key, which it itself generated for this purpose, and only it (the client) has control of the private key. Have you the appropriate PKI to do the encrypted JWT properly? Or are you expecting to  only utilise the HMAC-based JWT that has no encryption at all and relies on only signature verification (and therefore all claims are public, not protected).

To summaries, there are 2 distinct modes of JWT; 1) HMAC-based that uses signatures where the same inputs are needed on client to verify the signature as was used on server to generate the signature, and this is for integrity only, there is no encryption to protect data. 2) encryption-based JWT that uses a public key for signature verification and the private key used by clients to decipher the encrypted claims data.

1 requires PKI, 2 doesn't.
2 has no data protection and is useful for stateless claims that are intended to be public and therefore verification of the 'claims' before use is how you gain security assurance. Whereas 1 offers the security characteristic of confidentiality and if the PKI is done correctly (private keys are never shared) then the confidential claims data can have more private use cases.

Comment: To give you more details of the code, I am using exactly the sample code provided on GitHub, at https://github.com/sangonzal/jwt-validation-java. No changes from this sample code.

Comment: that code repo has a link to a post https://sgonzal.com/2020/04/06/jwt-validation.html which explains the portion I detailed about JWKS too, this is where the public keys are obtained to do signature verification, do not generate a new public key because then you cannot reproduce he same signature as the server who doesn't have your generated public key